# is index still effective after data has been selected?

Tags: sql-server, join, indexing

I have two tables that I want to join, they both have index on the column I am trying to join.

QUERY 1

```
SELECT * FROM [A] INNER JOIN [B] ON [A].F = [B].F;
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM [A]) [A1] INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) [B1] ON [A1].F=[B1].F
```

the first query clearly will utilize the index, what about the second one?
after the two select statements in the brackets are executed, then join would occur, but my guess is the index wouldn't help to speed up the query because it is pretty much a new table..

Comment: Effectively, both queries return the same result.
Both should also use the indexes ( check the query plan )
The real question is why you would ever want to use query2?

Comment: "FROM [A]" and "FROM (SELECT * FROM [A]) As [A]" are the same thing.

Comment: @Jimbo, I abstracted this to a simpler case. Because the two sub queries are built at different stages and then combined to form a bigger query, that is why i have query 2 instead of query 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query isn't executed quite so literally as you suggest, where the inner queries are executed first and then their results are combined with the outer query. The optimizer will take your query and will look at many possible ways to get your data through various join orders, index usages, etc. etc. and come up with a plan that it feels is optimal enough.

If you execute both queries and look at their respective execution plans, I think you will find that they use the exact same one.

Here's a simple example of the same concept. I created my schema as so:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int, value int)
CREATE TABLE B (id int, value int)

INSERT INTO A (id, value)
VALUES (1,900),(2,800),(3,700),(4,600)

INSERT INTO B (id, value)
VALUES (2,800),(3,700),(4,600),(5,500)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_A ON A (id)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_B ON B (id)
```

And ran queries like the ones you provided.

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A) A1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) B1 ON A1.id = B1.id
```

The plans that were generated looked like this:

[image]

Which, as you can see, both utilize the index.

Comment: is this the case for a more complicated query? if i have two complicated sub queries with joins/conditions inside them, when i perform join on these two sub queries, I am not too sure if it will give the same execution plan that utilizes the indices. So I can only rely on the optimizer to make the decision at this point?

Comment: Yep, its up to the optimizer to determine how to get at the data no matter how complex the query is. Unless you decide to use hints, but that is not generally recommended for production environments.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are high that the SQL Server Query Optimizer will be able to detect that Query 2 is in fact the same as Query 1 and use the same indexed approach.

Whether this happens depends on a lot of factors: your table design, your table statistics, the complexity of your query, etc. If you want to know for certain, let SQL Server Query Analyzer show you the **execution plan**. Here are some links to help you get started:

- [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Examining Query Execution Plans](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses [predicate pushing](http://www.davewentzel.com/content/nested-views-performance-and-predicate-pushdown) (a.k.a. *predicate pushdown*) to move query conditions as far toward the source tables as possible. It doesn't slavishly do things in the order you parenthesize them. The optimizer uses complex rules--what is essentially a kind of geometry--to determine the *meaning* of your query, and restructure its access to the data as it pleases in order to gain the most performance while still returning the same final set of data that your query logic demands.

When queries become more and more complicated, there *is* a point where the optimizer cannot exhaustively search all possible execution plans and may end up with something that is suboptimal. However, you can pretty much assume that a simple case like you have presented is going to *always* be "seen through" and optimized away.

So the answer is that you should get just as good performance as if the two queries were combined. Now, if the values you are joining on are composite, that is they are the result of a computation or concatenation, then you are almost certainly not going to get the *predicate push* you want that will make the index useful, because the server won't or can't do a seek based on a partial string or after performing reverse arithmetic or something.

May I suggest that in the future, before asking questions like this here, you simply examine the execution plan for yourself to validate that it is using the index? You could have answered your own question with a little experimentation. If you still have questions, then come post, but in the meantime try to do some of your own research as a sign of respect for the people who are helping you.

To see execution plans, in SQL Server Management Studio (2005 and up) or SQL Query Analyzer (SQL 2000) you can just click the "Show Execution Plan" button on the menu bar, run your query, and switch to the tab at the bottom that displays a graphical version of the execution plan. Some little poking around and hovering your mouse over various pieces will quickly show you which indexes are being used on which tables.

However, if things aren't as you expect, don't automatically think that the server is making a mistake. It may decide that scanning your main table without using the index costs less--and it will almost always be right. There are many reasons that scanning can be less expensive, one of which is a very small table, another of which is that the number of rows the server statistically guesses it will have to return exceeds a significant portion of the table.

Answer (score 0):

These both queries are same. The second query will be transformed just same as first one during transformation.

However, if you have specific requirement I would suggest that you put the whole code.Then It would be much easier to answer your question.